# Let's Encrypt: How to manually test the certbot renewal process?

Tags: lets-encrypt, manual-testing, certbot

I have a working setup where [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificates are generated with [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/). I wonder how you effectively test whether the renewal will work in production.

The certificates last for 90 days. Is there a way to reduce the lifespan to, for instance, 10 minutes, to see if the renewal works? (Using the staging system for that is fine.)

If you have an alternative approach how to make sure that your renewal code works (without having to wait for 90 days), it would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use "certbot renew --force-renewal"

https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#configuration-file

> --force-renewal, --renew-by-default
>
> If a certificate already exists for the requested
> domains, renew it now, regardless of whether it is
> near expiry. (Often --keep-until-expiring is more
> appropriate). Also implies --expand. (default: False)

Answer (score 20):

You use the `--dry-run` option. E.g.:

```
$ sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

From `certbot -h`:

> certbot [SUBCOMMAND] [options] [-d DOMAIN] [-d DOMAIN] ...
>
> ...
>
> --dry-run         Test "renew" or "certonly" without saving any certificates
>   to disk

This ensures that the certbot can validate your domain with your current configuration.

If you really want to save the certificates to disk and see if your system is using the new cert, then you can also use the `--force-renewal` option. In that case, you should visit your website and check that the active certificate is the new one. If it isn't, you likely need to adjust your cronjob to restart your web server. E.g.:

```
certbot renew && service apache24 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that `renew` doesn't like working in conjunction with domain-specific renewals, as per (certbot v1.22.0):

> Currently, the renew verb is capable of either renewing all installed certificates that are due to be renewed or renewing a single certificate specified by its name. If you would like to renew **specific certificates by their domains, use the `certonly` command instead.** The renew verb may provide other options for selecting certificates to renew in the future.

Taking this into account, you might want to consider using the following command:
`certbot certonly --dry-run -d my.domain.com`

---

**References:**

- [Renewing certificates (Certbot docs)](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#renewing-certificates) - One of the last paragraphs goes into this domain-specific behaviour